Mrs. /ˈmɪsɪz/ : final voicing
Mrs. /ˈmɪsɪz/ is a contraction of mistress /ˈmɪstrəs/.
Then, where does the final vocing in the contraction come from?
Is this voicing part of some general phonological process?

I haven't been able to find anything that explained why it lost the /r/ and /t/ sounds. But it's probably similar to the way "madam" became "ma'am".

Words that are used frequently often get contracted.

I often pronounce that as /ˈmɪzɪz/.

The 1907 NED (precursor of OED) had it with final /s/ only, and final /s/ is an option in American English (MW, OED). It's not surprising that it became voiced, but I doubt you'll get a definitive explanation as to why: whether it's by analogy with "misses", or similar to diminutives like "Chas"/"Chaz", pronounced with final /z/ or even more random. Certainly it's common for voiceless sounds to become voiced or vice versa.

@StuartF Yes it's common, but always in certain phonoogical contexts: such as? BTW, it's missus or missis https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/missus#English
